# 8086 Programming with Time Restriction

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

I have a program in 8086 that performs some tasks clearly and I want to add a time constraint to my program. If my program does not perform all tasks within 120 seconds, the program needs to be stopped. How can I do that?

> My program generates a random number and does some operations on it and gives some outputs.

```
org 100h 

;CALL TIMER_DISPLAY

GO:
MOV AL,0
MOV ROW,AL
CALL COORDINATE
CALL CLEAR_SCREEN
CALL RANDOM_NUMBER
MOV AL,R
AND AL,5
MOV KEY,AL   
MUL R
ADD AL,5
MOV DL,5
DIV DL
MOV KEY1,AH
CMP KEY1,0
JNE GO
LEA BX,M1
CALL DISPLAY_MESSAGE

MOV AL,KEY
OR AL,R
MOV KEY2,AL
CMP KEY2,0
JE GO
CALL COORDINATE
LEA BX,M2
CALL DISPLAY_MESSAGE

MOV AL,KEY
ADD AL,R
SAR AL,2
MOV KEY3,AL
CMP KEY3,0
JE GO 
CALL COORDINATE
LEA BX,M3
CALL DISPLAY_MESSAGE

MOV AL,KEY
XOR AL,R
MOV KEY4,AL
CMP KEY4,0
JE GO 
CALL COORDINATE
LEA BX,M4
CALL DISPLAY_MESSAGE

MOV AL,KEY
MOV DL,R
MUL DL
MOV KEY5,AL
CMP KEY5,0
JE GO   
CALL COORDINATE
LEA BX,M5
CALL DISPLAY_MESSAGE

ret

M1 DB 'LOCK 1 WAS OPENED', '$' 
M2 DB 'LOCK 2 WAS OPENED', '$'
M3 DB 'LOCK 3 WAS OPENED', '$'
M4 DB 'LOCK 4 WAS OPENED', '$'
M5 DB 'LOCK 5 WAS OPENED AND I AM OUT ', 01, '$' 

R DB ?

KEY DB ?

KEY1 DB ? 
KEY2 DB ?
KEY3 DB ?
KEY4 DB ?
KEY5 DB ?

ROW DB 0
```

> There is a procedure here to generate random numbers

```
; -- RANDOM NUMBER GENERATION PROCEDURE --
RANDOM_NUMBER PROC

MOV AH,00H ; INTERRUPTS TO GET SYSTEM TIME        
INT 1AH ; CX:DX NOW HOLD NUMBER OF CLOCK TICKS
 
MOV AX,DX
XOR DX,DX
MOV CX,10    
DIV CX
MOV R,DL   

MOV AX,0

RET
RANDOM_NUMBER ENDP
```

> Procedures to set coordinate, display messages and clear screen.

```
; -- DISPLAY MESSAGE --
DISPLAY_MESSAGE PROC

MOV AL,0 
MOV AH,09H
MOV DX,BX
INT 21H

RET
DISPLAY_MESSAGE ENDP

; -- SET COORDINATE --
COORDINATE PROC

MOV AH,2H
MOV BH,0            
MOV DH,ROW
MOV DL,0
INT 10H

INC ROW

RET
COORDINATE ENDP

; -- CLEAR SCREEN --
CLEAR_SCREEN PROC

MOV AH,7        
MOV AL,0        
MOV CX,0        
MOV DX,184FH    
MOV BH,7        
INT 10H      

RET
CLEAR_SCREEN ENDP
```

> Procedures for calling timer display and synchronize it with real time.

```
; -- TIMER DISPLAY --
TIMER_DISPLAY PROC

#START=LED_DISPLAY.EXE#
;#MAKE_BIN#   
NAME "TIMER"

MOV AX,120
OUT 199,AX

X1: 
CALL SYNCHRONIZE_TIMER_DISPLAY
DEC AX
OUT 199,AX
CMP AX,0
JG X1

HLT

RET
TIMER_DISPLAY ENDP

; -- SYNCHRONIZE TIMER DISPLAY --
SYNCHRONIZE_TIMER_DISPLAY PROC

PUSH AX 

MOV CX, 0FH
MOV DX, 4240H
MOV AH, 86H
INT 15H

POP AX

RET
SYNCHRONIZE_TIMER_DISPLAY ENDP
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? What errors do you get from your attempts?

Comment: Thank you Mikkel. When i called the procedure which is first comment row in my code, program waits 120 seconds and then does its bussiness. I want my program does both at the same time

Answer (score 5):

Because you use `int 1Ah`, I assume that "8086" means "PC compatible" (there are a few computers using the 8086 CPU not being PC compatible).

**Theoretical background**

In this case you might hook hardware interrupt IRQ 0 which is SW interrupt #8 on CPU side:

On a PC compatible system the timer will trigger the timer interrupt (IRQ 0) once in some timer interval. This is like an `int 8` instruction in software.

By default the timer is configured to a frequency of 18.2 Hz, so `int 8` will be called 182 times in 10 seconds or 2184 times in 120 seconds.

An interrupt instruction (`int`) will push 6 bytes (flags, CS and IP) on the stack and then jump to the *far* address (segment:offset) stored at the address `0:(4*n)`.

Example: If `0x1234` is stored at address `0:0x20` and `0x5678` is stored at address `0:0x22`, the `int 8` instruction will jump to address `0x5678:0x1234`.

When the interrupt routine is entered, the first 4 bytes on the stack (`ss:sp`) contain the far address of the next instruction to be executed after the interrupt; this address can be modified.

**Obstacles**

Please note that the hardware cannot execute any interrupts when the interrupts are disabled by the `cli` instruction. In this case you have no chance to limit the time of your program.

Another problem could be the DOS and BIOS calls:

If the 120 seconds are reached inside a BIOS call (e.g. `int 10h`) or even a DOS call (`int 21h`) and you interrupt your program, you may crash the entire operating system!

**Sample code**

Please also note that I'm normally using GNU assembler, which has a different syntax. So maybe some lines in my example have to modified a bit because your assembler recognizes a syntax error.

```
install:
  ; Remember the location of the original stack
  mov origStack, sp
  mov origStack+2, ss
  ; First we copy the original address of the "int 8" interrupt
  ; to the variable "origAddress"
  mov ax, 0
  mov es, ax
  mov ax, [es:20h]
  mov origAddress, ax
  mov ax, [es:22h]
  mov origAddress+2, ax
  ; We disable hardware interrupt generation
  ; This ensures that "int 8" cannot be generated between the
  ; next two instructions when [0:20h] already contains the
  ; new value but [0:22h] still contains the old one (so the
  ; combination of [0:20h] and [0:22h] is invalid)
  cli
  ; We write the address of our handler to 0:0x20
  mov word ptr [es:20h], offset hookHandler
  mov [es:22h], cs
  ; Now we can enable interrupt generation again
  sti

  ; Actually perform the program
  ...

  ; Uninstall the interrupt hook
  cli
  call uninstallHook
  ; The program finishes normally
  ...

; If the program took longer than 120s, we get here!
timeoutCode:
  cli
  ; Ensure DS contains the correct value
  push cs
  pop ds
  ; Restore the original stack
  lss sp, origStack
  ; Uninstall the hook
  call uninstallHook
  ; The program finishes due to a timeout
  ...

uninstallHook:
  ; Uninstall the hook; note: "cli" has already been called!
  mov ax, 0
  mov es, ax
  mov ax, origAddress
  mov [es:20h], ax
  mov ax, origAddress+2
  mov [es:22h], ax
  sti
  ret

; The actual handler is called 182 times in 10 seconds
; Note that a handler must not modify any registers but
; it must "push" all registers that it modifies and
; restore the original values using "pop"
hookHandler:
  ; Decrement the variable "timeout"
  dec word ptr [cs:timeout]
  ; Is it zero?
  jnz notZero
  ; It is zero; replace the address of the instruction
  ; that is executed after the interrupt by "timeoutCode"
  push bp
  mov bp,sp
  mov word ptr [ss:bp+2], timeoutCode
  mov word ptr [ss:bp+4], cs ; (segment of timeoutCode)
  pop bp
notZero:
  ; Jump to the original handler of the BIOS which will
  ; do the rest (e.g. handle the interrupt controller)
  jmp dword ptr [cs:origAddress]

origAddress DW 0,0
origStack   DW 0,0
timeout     DW 2184
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to halt the program immediately from withing this *hookHandler* ignoring that BIOS/DOS calls could be in progress. The safe way to do this, is to just set a flag in the *hookHandler* and have the program pick it up in its main loop.

Comment: You're missing a `CS:` override prefix on `dec word ptr timeout`.

Comment: @SepRoland About your first comment: Yes, that's true. However, I understood the initial question in a way that it should be possible to interrupt the program even if the program really hangs (e.g. an unwanted endless "inner" loop due to a programming error...)